# Identifying a specific control created programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating multiple rows of controls programmatically; each containing a checkbox and a textbox.

I would like to somehow identify the id of a checkbox so it will know which textbox to delete. What would be the best way to approach this?

Comment: Can you post the code here? You can delete using the object used to create the checkbox. var obj = new CheckBox();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make up some sort of naming pattern, for example "cbx-[row num]" for the checkbox and "txt-[row num]" for the text box.

This way you'll have a bunch of controls named "cbx-1, cbx-2, cbx-3" and matching text boxes named "txt-1, txt-2, txt-3". Finding a matching "txt-X" for "cbx-X" should be pretty simple.

EDIT: You can use System.Web.UI.FindControl(string) to find a control by it's id attribute.

Comment: That definitely seems flexible. I will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Your creating the control, so you have control over its name. Give it a GUID or a sequential numbering of your making.

But ... perhaps the issue is one of ownership. Your question implies that you can only access the control by name. Since you pro grammatically created it, that implies you have a reference to it. So keep a reference to controls you create.

Now, drilling up the application, if you wish to delete it that implies you already know what to delete which begs the question why do you need a name?

Sorry if these are not the answers your after but I hope they pose useful questions about design.

Comment: Thanks for asking me those questions. I tend to not ask myself enough questions, good thing you did :)